# Lost Session when AddModelError

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Friends,

I do not know why, but every time I add a ModelError my session is lost. Can someone tell me how I can work around / fix it?

```
Session[CtSessionName + SessionId] = _ListaAcaoMenuInfo;
AcaoMenuInfoExt _SelecionadoAcaoMenuExt = 
    _ListaAcaoMenuInfo.Where(p => p.Id_acao == id)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

if (_SelecionadoAcaoMenuExt.Is_AcaoInicial)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, 
                             "Error! Try Again, and Again, And Again!");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the snippet you provided is not relevant to the problem. What do you mean by `lost session`? You can't find values you've previously stored inside? If this is the case where are these `CtSessionName` and `SessionId` variables coming from? Do they have the same values when you try to read from the session?

Comment: Friend, I've checked numerous times, but they always have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friend but thats impossible. AddModelError's code path never touches Session at all.

When you access session after the AddModelError its gone?  Or are you outputting those values and they are not showing up on the screen?

Comment: My friend, this is embarrassing, but I found the problem.

The problem was to send the object to the page. The random value of the Session was obtained properly, but it was not sent correctly.

Comment: You know how I can close this question?

Comment: @Ph.E: The best way to close a question you've answered yourself is to post an answer stating how you fixed the problem, then mark it as answer.